# Почему на stackoverflow нету редиректа на протокол https?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, https

Почему на stackoverflow нету редиректа на протокол https?
Он же раньше вроде был. Зачем его убрали?

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее, в чём польза от введения редиректа на https?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin http и https - два разных сайта. Если будет использоваться два протокола, будет идти разделение трафика. Что в свою очередь будет негативно сказываться на ранжировании в поисковых системах. Два- сейчас можно перехватить соединения и узнать данные от аккаунта пользователей, а  при использовании HTTPS, они будут передаваться в зашифрованном виде.

Comment: Юрий, рекомендую вам оформить это как новое [meta-tag:предложение]. Выглядит довольно разумно. Только это наверняка должно будет коснуться не только ru.SO, но и всей сети.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Хорошо, в самое ближайшее время оформлю.

Answer (score 5):

На сколько я могу знать, перенаправления с HTTP на HTTPS никогда не было.

Comment: значит я с ютубом перепутал. Но всё рано, почему нету редиректа?

Comment: Потому что он не нужен :)

Comment: @Qwertiy http и https - два разных сайта. Если будет использоваться два протокола, будет идти разделение трафика. Это раз, два - сейчас я залогинен на сайте, и если использовать перехватчики сниферы пакетов, то то что там передается можно использовать для взлома аккаунта. Три - если он не нужен тогда зачем его вообще сюда прикрутили?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что не нужен редирект, а не https. Каждый сам выбирает, что ему по душе - http или https. Именно поэтому я по возможности все ссылки пишу через `//` без протокола.